# Adding onclick listeners to overlapping widgets in FrameLayout not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-widget

I have a FrameLayout with multiple ImageViews as shown in the image.[image]

I have registered listeners to all these Imageviews.
I have positioned the ImageViews using android:layout_gravity, android:paddingLeft and android:paddingRight due to which the `images are overlapping`.

My Activity class is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ivbglogin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bglogin);
    ivlogin = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login);
    tvlogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvlogin);

    ivbgsignup = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgsignup);
    ivsignup = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.signup);
    tvsignup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvsignup);

    ivbglogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    ivlogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvlogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    ivbgsignup.setOnClickListener(this);
    ivsignup.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvsignup.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bglogin:
        Toast.makeText(AstralPadActivity.this, "bglogin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.login:
        Toast.makeText(AstralPadActivity.this, "login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.tvlogin:
        Toast.makeText(AstralPadActivity.this, "tvlogin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        openLoginDialog();

        break;

    case R.id.bgsignup:
        Toast.makeText(AstralPadActivity.this, "bgsignup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.signup:
        Toast.makeText(AstralPadActivity.this, "signup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case R.id.tvsignup:
        Toast.makeText(AstralPadActivity.this, "tvsignup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    }
}
```

The Framwlayout is

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:background="@drawable/start_bottombg" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bglogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="194dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/start_loginbg" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="200dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_login" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvlogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="120dp"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bgor"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/start_or" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bgsignup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="190dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/start_signupbg" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_signup" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvsignup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="200dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</FrameLayout>
```

So when I click on the brown ImageView, it is calling the green one. 
I want to know how to register listeners to each one of these elements and invoke those specific listeners on click of respective widgets please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You click on the brown view, and the green view's listener is called? Are you sure? They aren't even overlapping. Perhaps you made a copy/paste error?

Comment: Agreed, that sounds more like you have a quirk in your code. Can you include the code in your activity?

Comment: I have edited the question to contain all the details now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because I was using `android:paddingLeft="200dp"` instead of `android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"`. Because of the padding the images were overlapping. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't run into this before, but it sounds like you're encountering (for lack of a better term) undefined behaviour. Is using a `RelativeLayout` an option? If not, then adjusting dimensions to prevent the overlap? Barring that--try assigning separate anonymous listeners instead of one that inspects the widget's ID.

And remember to, every step of the way, crawl through in a debugger/trace file to verify that what you think is happening, is really happening.

Comment: I tried assigning separate anonymous listeners but the behavior is still the same. How do I adjust dimensions to prevent overlap?The overlap is happening because of `android:layout_gravity="center"  android:paddingLeft="100dp"`. How could this be avoided if i need to place the images in the specific positions? Could you  please elaborate.